# where did this faces-config.pageflow.xml file come from?

Tags: jsf, faces-config

I am migrating an application to jsf 1.2 and now out of the blue there is a new .metadata folder in the project root with a WebConent folder inside there with a WEB-INF folder still deeper and inside there we now have a super important looking faces-config.pageflow file.

I open it up and see it has references to all of my included files from other jsps.

What is the point of this file? Does it really need to be there? Is there a way to turn that crap off?

Answer (score 4):

It's part of JBoss JSF Tools plugin for Eclipse (and probably also other Eclipse-based JSF plugins I am not aware of). No, you can't turn it off, just configure your IDE to hide it if it is bothering you somehow.

Comment: And what would its purpose be ? The funny thing is that it appeared when I turned off the _Glassfish Web Extensions_ facet